# Why is jQuery's $.type() defined to return "object" instead of "error" for native ECMAScript Error objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Update:** I have created a ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12191

---

jQuery's [`$.type()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/) function returns the `[[Class]]` internal property (lower-cased) of an object. E.g.:

```
$.type( {} ) // "object"
$.type( [] ) // "array"
$.type( function () {} ) // "function"
```

However, it only works for these types of objects:

```
Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object
```

specified by this section of jQuery's source code:

```
// Populate the class2type map
jQuery.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object".split(" "), function(i, name) {
    class2type[ "[object " + name + "]" ] = name.toLowerCase();
});
```

In addition to those types of objects, the ECMAScript standard defines corresponding `[[Class]]` internal properties for these:

```
Arguments Error JSON Math
```

This is specified in this sentence of the ECMAScript standard (in [section 8.6.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)):

> The value of the [[Class]] internal property of a host object may be
>   any String value except one of "Arguments", "Array", "Boolean",
>   "Date", "Error", "Function", "JSON", "Math", "Number", "Object",
>   "RegExp", and "String".

`$.type` returns `"object"` for those types of objects:

```
$.type( new Error ) // "object"
$.type( JSON ) // "object"
$.type( Math ) // "object"
(function () { $.type( arguments ); /* "object" */ }())
```

instead of `"error"`, `"json"`, `"math"`, and `"arguments"`, which are the actual `[[Class]]` values here (capitalized).

I would like to make it clear that `$.type` could return those correct values if it wanted to, since it uses the `Object.prototype.toString.call()` retrieval method, which returns `"[object Error]"` for `Error` objects, for instance.

So, why does jQuery report `"object"` instead of those four values? I could understand `JSON` and `Math`, since those are not instances, but singleton objects. And I could even understand `arguments`, since that is an automatically provided object, instead of an instance explicitly created by a JavaScript program (as in `var args = new Arguments;`). Buy why errors? I don't see what makes `Error` objects special (compared to the other native types, like `Date`, `Array`, etc.).

### **tl;dr**

```
$.type( new Error ) // why does this return "object" instead of "error"?
```

---

**Update:** Just to clarify one thing: I know why `$.type` returns `"object"` for `Error` instances, as I have looked into its source code, and found the code that is responsible for this behavior. I would like to know why `$.type` is defined to behave in such a manner.

Comment: Are you asking why jQuery made this decision? Cos you seem to know why it returns `"object"`

Comment: @Esailija I don't know if it's a decision. Ah, I see what you mean. I would like to know why it's defined to return "object"... I'll make that clear in my question...

Comment: Did you make a ticket about it on jQuery's tracker or ask it in their dev forum?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate in the Developing jQuery Core forum. https://forum.jquery.com/developing-jquery-core

Comment: Just tested, `Object.prototype.toString.call(new TypeError);` returns `[object Error]` for IE6+, Opera 9+, Chrome 1+, FF 14, Safari 3.2+ (previous versions untested). The value is reliable, so I see no reason for excluding it.

Comment: @KevinB What matters is if this question is appropriate for *this* forum, and I think it is. I prefer Stack Overflow over any other forum.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it's merely to save bytes on features that people won't use. A 1-byte difference in jQuery probably translates into Megabytes or Gigabytes of data-transfer each day.

Comment: Everyone here is assuming why they did this. Ask on the jQuery Core Dev list! Ask the people who write it, not the people who use it.

Comment: I dislike the jQuery forums too, but if you want a direct answer from one of the core developers, the best people to ask are the core developers!

Comment: Maybe we should just read the docs for [`$.type`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.type/)... *"If the object has an internal [[Class]] equivalent to one of the browser's built-in objects, the associated name is returned."* Clearly this behavior is a bug, as it doesn't fit the documented behavior.

Comment: @epascarello I intend to open a ticket later. However, I don't think it would be polite to contact the core devs directly (if that's what you meant).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas The jQuery core team has [a forum](https://forum.jquery.com/developing-jquery-core), ask the question there as pointed out by a couple of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I submitted a ticket here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12191. It has been classified as a bug, and it is expected to be fixed in version 1.8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Its because jQuery's authors either forgot about that type or they didn't care about it.

Since

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( new Error );
```

will correctly return `[object Error]`.

So, if you're cool to have a slightly longer comparison strings, here we go:

```
(function( type ) {
    console.log( type(new Error) );
}( Function.prototype.call.bind( Object.prototype.toString )));
```

---

Beside that, there are other "types" which jQuery doesn't care about like `JSON` or **any** `DOMElement`. For instance, `$.type( JSON )` also returns `object` while the above `type` methods correctly returns `[object JSON]`.

Another example `$.type( document.body )` again returns `object` where my simple `type()` methods again correctly returns `[object HTMLBodyElement]`.

So long story short, jQuery does not abstract all `[[Class]]` values from all available types. There might be a reason for beeing browser compatible, but for the `Error` type, there is none.

---

Actually there are a zillion types, alone for all the `DOM` objects. I can imagine that the jQuery authors only wanted to support `native object types` and no `host object types` which essentially `JSON` and any `DOMxxxElement` etc. are. I'm not sure about the `Error object` whether its native or host tho.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. There must be a reason why they explicitly decided to exclude `"error"` from the set of return values.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: its the truth anyway. Unless jQuery wants to support like netscape navigator 1.5 or IE4.

Comment: The `JSON` object and `Error` objects are native. As I stated in my question, the ECMAScript standard defines 12 different `[[Class]]` values, and `$.type` only reports 8 of those 12. I can understand why `"json"`, `"math"`, and `"arguments"` got excluded. It's the `"error"` type that puzzles me.

Comment: +1 "forgot" or "didn't care" would seem to be the two most likely scenarios. Unless perhaps they're concerned about confusion with `$.error`. If they're going to have a `type` function, it would seem sensible to represent all the possible *native* types. Not representing `Arguments` surprises me the most.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the `Error` type was considered unreliable, a lot of code `throws` *things*, that needn't be returned by the `Error` constructor:

```
function foo()
{
    throw 'I\'m what a lot of people call an error';
}
try
{
    foo();
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(e));//[object String]
}
```

The omission of `Arguments` is even simpler to explain: `'use strict';` rather limits what you can do with the arguments object. I think it better not to promote the usage of it too much, and so does John, I think. (sorry, never spell his last name correctly - I'm not on 1st name basis with the man, though).

Math is, by many considered a bad idea for an object, it should've been just a set of functions (according to most JS people). Anyway, when would anyone pass the 1 Math instance to the `$.type` method? you've just *Typed the Constructor!* what purpose could it possibly serve to have that repeated to you?

JSON is an object, older versions of IE don't support it, so you have to include a file (like you have to do with jQuery) to have the `JSON` object. It's not in any way a native type, but well written format sprouted from DC's mind. What else can JS say about it, other then the fact that it's an object?

Comment: I've been downvoted twice here, with no explanation as to why. I'm ok with down votes, but if I made a mistake I'd like to know what part of my answer is wrong. At least give me a chance to learn or better explain myself

Comment: (I didn't down-vote.) Yes, `throw` accepts strings or any other value, but that doesn't mean that `Error` objects aren't reliable. I'm not sure how that is related to `$.type` not recognizing `Error` objects. As for `Math`, could you back up that statement with a source? I've never heard the opinion that it's a "bad idea" before. I certainly don't agree with that. Also, a set of functions? You mean global functions? As for `JSON`, it *is* a native object type. It has a `"JSON"` `[[Class]]` value, and it is specified in the ECMAScript standard. It is one of the 12 ECMAScript object types.

Comment: Ok, you're right when you say that recognizing error objects has little to do with what is actually thrown. But it might prove risky to rely on what `$.type` returns in those cases since a thrown value needn't be an error object. As far as `Math` is concerned: Douglas Crockford is my source, but I can't find the article ATM (not my machine I'm working on now), but I did find a youtube clip (series of 3 or for, each ~1 hour long) in which he talked about this, too. Funcions, should have been `methods` - and properties, too. `JSON` is ECMA5, so older implementations won't support it yet.

Comment: Actually, I think that's an argument *for* `$.type` returning the more correct "error" value. For instance, `throw {message:"..."}` and `throw new Error("...")`. Here, only the second throwee is an `Error` instance (the first one is a plain object). If `$.type` worked correctly, we could distinguish between those two object values. (For the first one, it would return "object", and for the second one "error".) But no, `$.type` returns "object" for both throwees. `throw` being able to throw *any* value is one of the reasons why we *want* `$.type` to be able to recognize `Error` objects.

Comment: What? Crockford? I watch *all* his stuff, and I can't remember hearing him speak negatively about `Math`. Please provide the video if you can.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Found it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M it's  ~16.30 minutes in, when he starts of with `one mistake that JavaScript copied from Java... ` after he talks about using radix when with `parseInt`

Comment: Thanks for finding it. I'm not sure how to interpret his words. He says that "it's not useful", only to say (in the next sentence) that it contains useful methods. I would love to know how he would have implemented those methods instead. *** Above, you said "should have been methods". What do you mean by that? Number methods?

Comment: I meant that `Math` is an object, that contains methods like `Math.round()`... what DC means when he says it's not useful he means that instead of having to write `Math.round(10/3);` it would've made more sense to have these methods on the Number prototype, like `toPrecision()` is, so you can write `(10/3).round();` or have them as methods of the global object. I think he has a point

Comment: Yes, having them as Number methods (or static Number functions where appropriate) would be nice. However, defining them as global function would be a mistake, IMO.

Comment: Agreed, Number functions, rather then global functions makes most sense